# I have multiple google accounts. How can I hide some of them from the Gmail and Calendar apps?

Tags: sync, gmail

I have several google accounts I use for different purposes (i.e. my main everything account, one to log in to less secure websites / games, one shared account for work, my wife's Play store account).

I only use my main account for the gmail app and two accounts for the calendar app. I have customized the synchronization options under settings -> General --> accounts but even though I disable synchronization of Gmail, the accounts still show up in the calendar and gmail apps. How can I make these go away?

I use a rooted Note 3 on t-mobile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On Android 6 and lower you can install Xposed Framework and then XPrivacy module for Xposed. In Xprivacy, deny access to accounts for the gmail app. Then add the account you want visible to the white list.

You can have a separate white list for every app, so you can have different accounts show for different apps.

Some apps get their account list from Google Play Services, and I've had weird things happen when trying to block accounts from that. But gmail and calendar work fine. Hangouts has a sign out feature, so you don't really need to block, but blocking works there, too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will hide your accounts from gmail but you can turn syncing off for gmail and calendar for accounts you don't want to sync..! 
You can change the account sync settings from within settings-> Google then choose the account you want change sync settings of.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly how you might so that, is a many varied answer. Bur it can be done. For instance. Android itself pretty much requires you to have a google account, its used as your primary backup. This account ibwouks suggest veing your most secured account. Being fortified with 2fa / ontpw and even havinf email or app prompts aby time the device is signed into or loged onto from a new source.

Then instead of signing your ither accounts into the device itself, you have the browsers. Firefox chrone chromium opera can all handle multiple accounts signed into then without actually being signed into the phone/pad itself. Almost all of the browsers have a way to lock thier access from from prying eyes. Chrome/chromium actually require you at least be signed into the app, just use another account youre not as concerned with hiding but havr if fortified also wth as man security mechanisms as gou can set. Firefox and opera also employ a sign in account for signing in and syncing.

Comment: Hi, this a friendly poke since I'm honestly confused why this post looks a bit unreadable compared to all your other posts. Would you [edit] this post to improve it? Thanks.