# Remove calendar accounts without removing gmail

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

My question is exactly the same as [I have multiple google accounts. How can I hide some of them from the Gmail and Calendar apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108650/i-have-multiple-google-accounts-how-can-i-hide-some-of-them-from-the-gmail-and) But since it's been 6 years since that post and much things have changed, I wanted to ask it again to see if there's currently a good way to do this.

Long story short: I have multiple google accounts (8 to be exact) and every one of the accounts show up as an account in google calendar even though I only use 1 of them. I turned off sync, but they still show up. How do I hide or get rid of the accounts in google calendar **without** getting rid of the gmail part of the google account. (Aka I want gmail, but not cal)

- I don't mind using another app
- My phone is not rooted
- I have Android 11

Comment: Remove those accounts from your device. Enable IMAP on each Gmail [only] account and then add each account as IMAP account in GMail app.

Comment: It would get rid of google drive and stuff too right? I just want the cal part gone.

Comment: Yes, that would remove all Google services of the removed accounts. You can have only everything of every account or nothing but GMail.

Comment: You can hide temporarily or remove an account (needs PC). From [calendar help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37188?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) //I haven't tried it

Comment: Or even more simple, from the calendar app (if you are using Google calendar), [deselct everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsaiw.png)!